# Symlink to python exec and the python exec have different sys paths. This causes ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, symlink, python3

I have a project with a virtual environment. 
My project structure is:

```
$ cd /path/to/project
$ tree . -L 2
.
├── venv
│   ├── bin
│   ├── include
│   ├── lib
│   ├── lib64 -> lib
│   ├── pip-selfcheck.json
│   └── pyvenv.cfg
├── py -> /path/to/project/venv/bin/python3
├── README.md
├── req.txt
└── source
    └── sym.py
```

I have scripts in the project directory tree,
which I want to run in the project directory tree
without activating the virtual environment. 
I have a symlink, `py`,
pointing to the actual location of the Python executable in the venv. 
This is to ensure that my Python executable isn't hardcoded in the scripts,
and can be quickly deployed anywhere, while still including a shebang.

Now, when I call the symlink `py` vs the actual Python executable,
`/path/to/project/venv/bin/python3`, things don't work (details below). 
One accompanying symptom that I've noticed is that
the `sys.path` value changes. 
The following is executed in the folder: `/path/to/project/source/`:

```
$ ls -l ../py
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 som cms-script-admins 45 Apr 17 19:39 ../py -> /path/to/project/venv/bin/python3

$ cat sym.py
import sys
print(sys.path)


$ ../py sym.py
['/path/to/project/source', '/usr/lib64/python36.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.6', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages']

$ /path/to/project/venv/bin/python3 sym.py
['/path/to/project/source', '/usr/lib64/python36.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.6', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload',        '/path/to/project/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages',    '/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

<sup>[Spaces added to the last line of output to facilitate comparison.]</sup>

As you can see, based on whether the symlink is executed or the direct exec is called, the sys paths are changing.

For example, the symlink includes `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages` but the actual executable in the venv includes `/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages`.

An example of the problem: 
When I try to import selenium, I get:

```
$ ../py
>>> import selenium
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Looks like you created a virtual environment - do you remember doing that?

Comment: @ajgringo619 yes, that's intentional. However while running the script, I don't wanna be in the virtual env. Since the python exec is the one in the virtual environment, I still get the same functionality of the venv without actually activating it.

Comment: I was able to reproduce your situation on my Mint 20 system. I think you might be better off writing a bash wrapper script that sources `/path/to/venv/bin/activate` before calling `python3`.

Comment: Before running script you can export PYTHONPATH to point folder where package is located